# How to detect letter of DVD/CD drive using batch code

Tags: batch-file

I need help from you guys.I have batch code that list all drive letter and save those to  drive.txt but I need it to list only letter of (DVD) disk drive that DVD/CD running in.Here is my batch code:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (if exist "%%~a:" Echo %%~a: >> drives.txt)
```

Thanks

Comment: does `wmic logicaldisk get caption,description` help you?

Answer (score 4):

instead of checking each possible drive letter, just ask windows for installed CD-Drives (DriveType 5):

```
(for /f "skip=1" %%d IN ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=5 get deviceid') DO echo/%%d )>drives.txt
```

Comment: @jumpjack at what level? `for` or `wmic`?

Comment: this is not an encyclopedia-like site, it's a question-and-answer site. The encyclopedia-like part of StackOverflow is called [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) and is currently in Beta status.